# Kafka consumers picking up the same message again

Tags: go, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I have a golang service with 30 instances. There is a topic with 3 partitions and a single consumer group listening to the messages. The issue we are facing is that each message is being picked up by the same consumer again and again with a gap of 24-30 hours.
I have confirmed that the message is being pushed to the topic once and even the message is same every time but the message is being picked up at different time intervals, e.g.:

- June 2nd 2021, 12:59:29.555
- June 3rd 2021, 20:33:11.438
- June 5th 2021, 12:08:40.710
- June 6th 2021, 12:34:39.188

Can someone please help with what the problem could be. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need 30 instances to consume from 3 partitions. Because partitions are not shared between consumer instances. So, if your topic has 3 partitions, your maximum number of consumer instances should be 3.
2. Re-Consuming can be happen if your consumers not commit the read massage after consumed. Look in to consumer commit interval and auto commit enabled or disabled. If your consumed message is not committed, then after rebalance happened to consumers, those messages can be re-consumed.

Comment: Yes, those many instances are not required for this particular use case. The service is serving other important flows and the instances are in line with the usual load. 
The message throughput for kafka would be low.
Cross checked the code and  the consumers are committing the read messages.

Comment: Try to share some logs , consumer group  describe output,